# Help with using Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, command-line-tool

So, I'm using Xcode to program with C++. I want to access the C++ tool but I'm having this problem.

This is what it looks like when opening a new project. Only for me, I don't have the 'Command Line Utility' option at the end.

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100305-gsab76ef7bkx5ihwwj94cui39t.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100305-gsab76ef7bkx5ihwwj94cui39t.jpg)

How can I get the 'Command Line Utility' option to be available. I need it to access the C++ tool.

Please and thank you!

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? (Check Xcode -> About Xcode in the menu.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this comment till now.
I'm using 3.2.1

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a reasonably current version of Xcode (e.g. 3.2.2) then the selection process is slightly different - you need `Application` -> `Command Line Tool` and then select `C++ stdc++` from the popup menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have Xcode v3.2

I find the command line utility under File > New Project > (Mac OS X) Application > Command Line Tool (in right pane). When you click on Command Line Tool in right pane you will see a drop down box that lets you select the language you want to use. Mine defaults to C but there is an option for "C++ stdc++".